# Convolution of two impulse functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

I was trying to solve fourier transform of $cos(2\pi f_0 t)u(t)$ where $u(t)$ is a unit step function,

$$
u(t) = \begin{cases}
  1 \text{ for t$\ge$ 0}\\      
  0  \text{ for $t< 0$}\\
\end{cases}
$$

As far i have done that 
$$
\mathscr{F}\{cos(2\pi f_0 t)u(t)\} = \mathscr{F}\{cos(2\pi f_0 t)\} * \mathscr{F}\{u(t)\}\\
= \frac{1}{2}[\delta(f-f_0)+\delta(f+f_0)]*[\frac{1}{2}\delta(f)+\frac{1}{2j\pi f}]
$$
I know that $\delta(f-f_0)*x(t) = x(f-f_0)$, so
$$
\frac{1}{2}[\delta(f-f_0)+\delta(f+f_0)]*[\frac{1}{2}\delta(f)+\frac{1}{2j\pi f}]\\
= \frac{1}{4j\pi (f-f_0)}+\frac{1}{4j\pi (f+f_0)}+\frac{1}{2}[\delta(f-f_0)+\delta(f+f_0)]*[\frac{1}{2}\delta(f)]
$$
but what is the value of $\frac{1}{2}[\delta(f-f_0)+\delta(f+f_0)]*[\frac{1}{2}\delta(f)] = ?$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every distribution $u$ one has $u(f) * \delta(f) = u(f)$ so,
$$\delta(f \pm f_0) * \delta(f) = \delta(f \pm f_0).$$